# Add image src to ArcGis Web AppBuilder popupTemplate

Tags: arcgis

I'm building an ArcGIS widget, and i added a popup, which i want to have an image inside of it, but every time i add an image (in different ways) from javascript (not sure how to do it from html since popup is a js element), i get empty src on the browser so image doesnt show

```
            var img = domConstruct.create("img", {
              src: "widgets/TowersConnection/images/Green-2G.png",
              alt: "Image Description",
              width: "300px",
              height: "300px",
            });

            return new PopupTemplate({
              title: "Location Information",
              description: img.outerHTML,
            });
```

and i tried the original way

```
            return new PopupTemplate({
              title: `${event.mapPoint.x},  ${event.mapPoint.y}`,
              description:
                `<div class="popup-content">` +
                "<img src='widgets/TowersConnection/images/Green-2G.png' alt='Image Description' " 

            });
```

any ideas would be appreciated.